# Akka timeouts starting event handlers

Tags: scala, akka

When I run my app using akka, it fails with the following exception:

```
Event Handler specified in config can't be loaded [com.despegar.hasp.impl.DummyLogEventHandler] due to [a06c8d75-0f07-40db-883a-16dc2914934bakka.event.Logging$LoggerInitializationException: Logger log1-DummyLogEventHandler did not respond with LoggerInitialized, sent instead [TIMEOUT]
```

DummyLogEventHandler is defined as:

```
class DummyLogEventHandler extends Actor {
   def receive = {
     case InitializeLogger(_) => sender ! LoggerInitialized
     case Error(cause, logSource, logClass, message) =>
     case Warning(logSource, logClass, message) =>
     case Info(logSource, logClass, message) =>
     case Debug(logSource, logClass, message) =>
   }
```

}

My configuration has the following lines:

```
event-handlers = ["my.app.DummyLogEventHandler"]
event-handler-startup-timeout = 15s
```

But I've also tried with the default logger:

```
event-handlers = []
```

and with slf4j (my app is using the logback backend and logging works ok):

```
event-handlers = ["akka.event.slf4j.Slf4jEventHandler"]
```

Neither of those event-handlers nor incrementing the timeout to 60 seconds have worked so far. Moreover, the timeout is thrown sporadically. When I ran a test suite, the exception is thrown in different tests every time.

Can you help me find a solution?

Thanks,
Alex.

Answer (score 3):

Try to set a larger timeout for the logger initialization :

For example in the conf file :

```
     akka {logger-startup-timeout = 25s }
```

checkout the doc

http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/general/configuration.html

Answer (score 1):

After discussion on [akka-user](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/akka-user/rnbcw9urWKI/GFba1-9mj6MJ) the following was found.

This problem is a symptom of configuring the `akka.actor.default-dispatcher` to be of `type = BalancingDispatcher`, which cannot work, see [the docs for that dispatcher type](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.1.2/java/dispatchers.html#Types_of_dispatchers):

- All the actors share a single Mailbox that they get their messages from.
- It is assumed that all actors using the same instance of this dispatcher can process all messages that have been sent to one of the actors; i.e. the actors belong to a pool of actors, and to the client there is no guarantee about which actor instance actually processes a given message.
- Sharability: Actors of the same type only

Answer (score 0):

In my case, adding the timeout setting in conf does not work, but setting system property directly like below works.

```html
System.setProperty("akka.logger-startup-timeout", "30s")
```